# Norm of the multiplication operator $f\mapsto (x\mapsto xf(x))$ on $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

We have a linear operator $T : L^2[a,b] \rightarrow L^2[a,b]$ (with $|a| \le |b|$), $f \mapsto (x \mapsto xf(x))$

Now I shall determine what $\Vert T\Vert$ is.

We clearly have $\Vert x \mapsto xf(x)\Vert \le   |b|\,\Vert f\Vert$, so $\Vert T\Vert \le |b|$. But do we also have $||T||=|b|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider $T$ applied to the functions $g_n=1_{[b-1/n,b]}/\|1_{[b-1/n,b]}\|$.